# How to perform DCT on the image in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, dct

```
public Rgb Jasnosc()
    {
        Byte rob =(byte)(0.299*this.r + 0.587*this.g + 0.114*this.b);
        Rgb ret;
        ret.r = rob;
        ret.g = rob;
        ret.b = rob;
        return ret;
    }
```

So i have this kind of structure, and i am changing the loaded image to a grayscaled.
My Problem is that i would like to use a similar method to perform DCT on the image, but i totally do not know how to do it. Here is the code i used to perform it:

```
public static Bitmap Jasnosc(Bitmap bitmapaWe)
    {
        int wysokosc = bitmapaWe.Height;
        int szerokosc = bitmapaWe.Width;

        Bitmap bitmapaWy = new Bitmap(szerokosc, wysokosc, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        BitmapData bmWeData = bitmapaWe.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, wysokosc, wysokosc), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        BitmapData bmWyData = bitmapaWy.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, wysokosc, wysokosc), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        int strideWe = bmWeData.Stride;
        int strideWy = bmWeData.Stride;

        IntPtr scanWe = bmWeData.Scan0;
        IntPtr scanWy = bmWyData.Scan0;

        unsafe
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < wysokosc; y++)
            {
                byte* pWe = (byte*)(void*)scanWe + y * strideWe;
                byte* pWy = (byte*)(void*)scanWy + y * strideWy;

                for (int x = 0; x < szerokosc; x++)
                {

                    ((Rgb*)pWy)[x] = ((Rgb*)pWe)[x].Jasnosc();
                    ((Rgb*)pWy)[y] = ((Rgb*)pWe)[y].Jasnosc();

                }
            }

        }
        bitmapaWy.UnlockBits(bmWyData);
        bitmapaWe.UnlockBits(bmWeData);

        return bitmapaWy;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use "[emguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)" ("OpenCV") for such operations.
This library is well designed in perfomance & exposes a lot of usefull Computer-Vision-Functions.

An [example](https://github.com/artemisvision/emgu_openCV/blob/master/Emgu.CV/Image.cs) for `DCT` can be found in the [Git repo](https://github.com/emgucv).

```
      /// <summary>
      /// performs forward or inverse transform of 2D floating-point image
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="type">Transformation flags</param>
      /// <returns>The result of DCT</returns>
      [ExposableMethod(Exposable = true, Category = "Discrete Transforms")]
      public Image<TColor, Single> DCT(CvEnum.CV_DCT_TYPE type)
      {
         Image<TColor, Single> res = new Image<TColor, float>(Width, Height);
         CvInvoke.cvDCT(Ptr, res.Ptr, type);
         return res;
      }
```

The [DCT-Function](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/ab1cef16-8f7f-306a-e17e-042523d5589a.htm) of EMGUCV is declared as:

```
public static void Dct(
    IInputArray src,
    IOutputArray dst,
    DctType flags
)
```

Comment: But I would like to make it from the very basics, by using the math forumla on each pixel, problem is in open cv it was used on greyscaled  brightness degree of the pixel. And that is what the math formula I have is for. But in C# I cannot find such thing as this brightness degree option of the pixel.